# The "Remove New User Restrictions" privilege page uses the wrong icon

Tags: discussion, editing, privileges

I'm not sure if you are able to edit the privilege pages at a certain reputation. but on the [Remove New User Restrictions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user) privilege page I noticed that the icon in the last sentence about how to add links is incorrect.

- the editor toolbar button [image: the editor toolbar button]

should be

- the editor toolbar button [image: the editor toolbar button]

I also believe that the heading text for this section could be a bit confusing to some users.

Current text says "**How do I add links to my posts?**".
I move that this be changed to "**How do I add links in my posts?**".
This will remove the ambiguity and question "is this a link inside my post or a link to my actual post" for example.

Comment: I don't agree with the text change - its current form is proper English and communicates its intent perfectly. Explaining how to add inbound links to your post in that context makes no sense, so there really isn't room for ambiguity. The text immediately after it also reinforces that when it speaks of formatting posts. If the icon is inconsistent that should definitely be changed though

Comment: Thanks @Clive I would agree that it is mostly clear and that the following text does support its meaning. I guess I assumed the lowest dominator to be lower than it probably is.

Comment: nothing wrong with that, you're right, I just think the ambiguity is too small to warrant the change - plus we'd end up in a debate about the exact new text to use and no-one wants that on a Sunday :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the icon shown in the privilege page should be the same icon users see in the site; probably users will find out which icon the privilege page is referring, but that is still confusing.
The reason you see that icon that is the privilege pages you see on every Stack Exchange site are the copy of the master pages visible on *Meta Stack Overflow*; this means that the pages on *Meta Stack Overflow* are editable (they are wiki pages), and the changes are then pushed to the rest of the Stack Exchange sites. Since [the privilege page on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user) contains the following Markdown, it is not possible to show a different icon basing in the site where the privilege pages are shown.

```
We use [Markdown][2] to format posts, so there are a variety of ways of adding links:

  - bare urls `http://example.com`
  - HTML `<a href="http://example.com">example link</a>`
  - Markdown `[example link](http://example.com)`
  - the editor toolbar button ![insert link toolbar button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSZui.png)
```

It would be possible, if there would be a placeholder for the image, which is then replace with the HTML markup for the correct icon. This is what is done in the [Participate in Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta) privilege page, for example.

```
### Where is meta?

There is a link to meta in the footer and header of every page.

Our meta naming convention is standard. The meta site for this site is at:

$MetaUrl
```

As for "add links to my posts," it is perfectly fine English that would be parsed as "add `<something>` to `<something>`" not as "add `<something that is pertinent to something>`."
Given the context, I doubt somebody would understand the sentence as referring to my post's links I can add in some place. If that were the meaning, I would imagine that "How do I link my posts?" or "How do I get my post's link?" would be the used sentence. That is a question that makes sense to ask on Stack Exchange, and the answer would be "click on the 'share' link you see after the post, and copy-paste the link shown in the dialog box." As for other languages, in English it is the context that determines the meaning of a sentence. For example, ["How are you?" or "How are you doing?" could not be asking how I feel](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/4527/95).

Comment: Thanks @kiamlaluno, As per my comments above with Clive, I agree that the sentence will not be misunderstood

Comment: I guess my first addition to Meta may have seemed a bit more aggressive than intended and realise that the issued raised are small. In future it will probably be more important as I am still entering into this community and learning.

Comment: Showing the right icon is a good suggestion; in my answer, I explained why the shown icon is that, but that doesn't mean I agree with changing the icon. I didn't find this post aggressive, and I apologize if my answer seemed aggressive.